# BitField with number of flags as parameter

Tags: c++, bit-fields

Lets assume I want to create a class BitField with binary flags and a constructor that defines how many of those flags there is: `BitField bitField(500)`. What's the best way to create such a class? Would be cool if I could read and set flag at offset and do bitwise operations on bitfield `getState(int index) const;`. Thanks!

Comment: `std::bitset<500>` or `std::vector<bool>`

Comment: Trying to write my own implementation for learning purposes. I know about those.

Comment: Even then, those are the answer.  What is the best way to do what others have done?  Do things like they did.

Comment: What's the point of learning when you don't know how it works under the hood? I want to know how bitset is implemented. So your answer is not for the problem I have.

Comment: You could look at the code that comes with your compiler.  That would show you how it works under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking for a [bitset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/), you can refer to the implementation of STL.

Answer (score -3):

**Here is my suggestion (not including the implementation itself):**

```
#include <limits.h>

template<unsigned int SIZE>
class BitField
{
public: //Constructors + Destructor
    BitField();
    virtual ~BitField();
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
public: //Assignment Operators
    virtual const BitField& operator=(const BitField& bitField);
    virtual const BitField& operator|=(const BitField& bitField);
    virtual const BitField& operator&=(const BitField& bitField);
    virtual const BitField& operator^=(const BitField& bitField);
    virtual const BitField& operator<<=(unsigned int shift);
    virtual const BitField& operator>>=(unsigned int shift);
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
public: //Unary Operators
    virtual BitField operator~() const;
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
public: //Binary Operators
    friend BitField operator|(const BitField& bitField1,const BitField& bitField2);
    friend BitField operator&(const BitField& bitField1,const BitField& bitField2);
    friend BitField operator^(const BitField& bitField1,const BitField& bitField2);
    virtual BitField operator<<(unsigned int shift) const;
    virtual BitField operator>>(unsigned int shift) const;
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
public: //Binary Comperators
    friend bool operator==(const BitField& bitField1,const BitField& bitField2);
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
protected:
    unsigned char m_flags[(SIZE-1)/CHAR_BIT+1];
};
```

Note: instanciate an object with `BitField<500> bitField` instead of `BitField bitField(500)`.

Comment: `virtual` aside, the destructor is unnecessary.

Comment: @Mooing Duck: Thanks, but if OP chooses to add other fields, then the destructor becomes necessary. And if OP further chooses to inherit the class, then the destructor being virtual also becomes necessary. In short, the purpose is to define a generic class which can be extended, either internally or with inheritance. For this reason, all member functions are `virtual`, and all member variables are `protected` instead of `private` (it also answers the redundantly-offensive comment made by @DeadMG above, though I see no reason to relate to that one in specific).